# printing page - each div takes new line

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, media

**html**:

```
  <div class="row container-overview">
    <div class="span1">
        <span>test1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
        <span>test1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
         <span>test1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="span1">
         <span>test1</span>
    </div>
```

refer [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e6ht5pnc/), it is taking single line in the screen but while printing each div with class span1 takes new line in chrome And IE, working in Firefox.

Comment: Working fine in chrome using your probided link

Answer (score 0):

use width auto for span1 class its may resolve you issue

Comment: I check your fiddle link in my chrome your op is in one line I cant see span text in new line & also check in IE or fire fox all browser result in same line